How to make music player play globally
I write a music box on my website, but as soon as I refresh the page, the music reloads. Is there any way to keep the music playing without reloading? Use javascript and PHP
I used localStorage, but it didn't have the desired effect.

Post code as a [mcve] (hint: click the brackets button <>).

I used localStorage to do what? what does "play globally" mean to you?

Listen when the page is refreshed, get the playback progress of the current music, use localStorage to store the current playback music information and playback progress, when the page loads completely, get the music information from localStorage playback and set the playback progress should be able to achieve the effect you want
// Before browser refresh
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", () => {
   // get music info and playback progress
   const musicInfo = {}
   localStorage.setItem("music", musicInfo)
})
      
// After the browser is refreshed
window.addEventListener("unload", () => {
   const musicInfo = localStorage.getItem("music")
   // music play logic
})

